# Create multiple documents with Storage Access Framework

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

I'm using an intent of type `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` to save a file on the device from my app. Is there a way to create multiple documents at once with this intent? I was thinking of using `EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE` but I don't know how to provide the number of documents I want to create.

Thanks for your help.